# ORA-12154 TNS can't resolve specified identifier

Tags: oracle

i'm trying to connect to my oracle server using a batch file, but while i try connecting i got the following error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I've already check the tnsnames.ora ad the identifier is spelled correctly; i've put in the environment's variable a new variable named TNS_ADMIN that point on my admin folder in the client section.

ty tnsname.ora is as following

```
  ORCL_SRVDATIORIO12 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = ORCL)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

If i try connecting to that server using SSMA for example, using the tnsnames mode (SID or the description name), connection will establish just fine; while running it in command line it return me the error.

Also if i try running

```
tnsping <my tnsname>
```

i'll get:

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-GEN-2019 14:36:59

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

File di parametri utilizzati:
C:\app\client\user\product\12.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Impossible finding name
```

So i checked the sqlnet.ora file and the directory path seems fine to me:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT, LDAP)
```

any suggestion?

EDIT: i solved by simply creating a new text file and copy past the previous contents in the new one.

Comment: Do you have any space characters in front of `ORCL_SRVDATIORIO12 =...`?

Comment: Do you have any `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` in your `sqlnet.ora` file?

Comment: i solved by simply creating a new text file and copy past the previous contents in the new one. Oracle magic

Answer (score 0):

you need to check `tnsnames.ora`. `tnsnames.ora` contains tns names and their connection declarations. You need to use appropriate tns name to connect your database.

```
tnsping <tns_name>  //tns_name is needed to be defined in tnsnames.ora
```

in your case

```
tnsping ORCL_SRVDATIORIO12 10
```

need to return success message. if it does not, it means that your connection decriber is wrong. In which case, you need to talk with your DBA